# Using sanitize_filename() during File Upload in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been looking into securing my files that are uploaded to my server.

I came across `$this->security->sanitize_filename()` in the documentation but I can't figure out how to use it for file names during file upload. I don't want someone to name a file something malicious like `Something<?php exit;?>.jpg` or something with slashes that could mess with url paths.

Does the file upload class in Codeigniter automatically use sanitize_filename? If not, how can I use it?

Do I need to do something with $_FILES first, then use sanitize_filename, then pass it to file_name in the upload config? How can I access the file name from $_FILES?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just added this to my file upload config.

```
$filename = $this->security->sanitize_filename($this->input->post('file'));

$config['file_name'] = $filename;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Security Helper for this.

encode_php_tags() to make php tags   to html entities.

Answer (score 0):

just add this config to your upload configs

```
.
.
$config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE
.
.
 $this->load->library('upload', $config); // Or $this->upload->initialize($config); if you already loaded the upload library
```

check the codeigniter user guide: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

This config encrypt the filename.